# Intel TBB can not be built: required make-tool (gmake) was not found?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make, tbb

I take this error when I work on cmake and I couldn't find how can I solve this problem. How can I download gmake tool? "make" tool works smoothly when I check on command prompt.

Here is the output of `make --version` : `GNU Make 4.2`
I am using Windows, working on CLion and uses MinGW as a toolchain. 
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
include("C:/yunus/Git/inteltbb/tbb/cmake/TBBBuild.cmake")

tbb_build(TBB_ROOT "C:/yunus/Git/inteltbb/tbb" CONFIG_DIR TBB_DIR)
```

Complete error message is like that:

```
-- Intel TBB can not be built: required make-tool (gmake) was not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Projects/deneme/cmake-build-debug
```

Comment: That's much too little information. What OS are you working on? Is the `make` you have actually GNU make (output of `make --version`, `which make`, and `which gmake`)? Can you give us a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` that reproduces the error? Can you give us the complete error message you are getting from `cmake`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edited question.

Comment: Some people install GNU make with the name "gmake" instead of "make".  Apparently the "Intel TBB" cmake files are expecting that.  You can simply copy your "make.exe" to "gmake.exe" and it will work (if that is indeed the problem).

Comment: Thanks to MadScientist, it works surprisingly. I didn't expect that. Now, I am cursing my computer.

Comment: @MadScientist: A (hard) link would be better than a copy (which would, among other things, not get updated).

Comment: Hard links will likely not help with updates.  Most updates, especially on Windows, don't copy new bytes on top of the existing file; they remove or rename the existing file first then copy over, which would break any hard link.  If you really wanted to survive upgrades easily you'd use a symlink gmake -> make not a hard link.  But of course, symlinks on Windows are problematic in many ways.